# How to make a validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a validation in my model of rails: The local team must be different the visiting team.local_team_id is an integer that represent a team and the same for visiting_team_id.This is my code:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :mathdate, :presence => true
    validate :mydate_is_date?
  validates :stage, :presence => true
  validates :stage, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,     less_than_or_equal_to: 6}
  validates :state, :presence => true
  validates :state, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,     less_than_or_equal_to: 3}
  validates :local_team_id, :presence => true
  validates :visiting_team_id, :presence => true
  validates :stadium_id, :presence => true

def mydate_is_date?
    errors.add(:contructiondate, 'must be a valid date') if !mathdate.is_a?(Date)

end
```

Hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: I have to accept that this question is simple haha. But I try to solve the previous question. after many attempts I could not solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a validation in Rails like so:

```
validate :team_ids

def team_ids
  # if you want to allow blank / nil values
  return if local_team_id.nil? && visiting_team_id.nil?

  if local_team_id == visiting_team_id
    errors.add(:local_team_id, "can't be equal to visiting_team_id")
    errors.add(:visiting_team_id, "can't be equal to local_team_id")
  end
end
```